# Which Autoconfigrations should be excluded while deploying a Springboot in Weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

When I deploy my springboot application on weblogic I get the following exception, but when I run it with maven runner it runs without error. I assume I need to exclude some AutoConfigurers but could not find out which ones.

```
Descriptor Exceptions:
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setResponses] or [getResponses] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray.setResponses([Lcom.mycell.comet.router.model.Response;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[responses]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setRequests] or [getRequests] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray.setRequests([Ljava.sql.SQLData;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeDirectCollectionMapping[requests]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setResponses] or [getResponses] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray.setResponses([Lcom.mycell.comet.router.model.Response;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[responses]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setRequests] or [getRequests] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray.setRequests([Ljava.sql.SQLData;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeDirectCollectionMapping[requests]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setResponses] or [getResponses] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray.setResponses([Lcom.mycell.comet.router.model.Response;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[responses]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.ResponseArray --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setRequests] or [getRequests] is not defined in the object [com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray.setRequests([Ljava.sql.SQLData;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeDirectCollectionMapping[requests]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.setupSession(XMLContext.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.setupSession(XMLContext.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.<init>(Context.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getBindingContextFromSpi(BindingContextFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:195)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:300)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:639)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:355)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:167)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:79)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2054)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2031)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1920)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: Looks like you've cut off some of the stack trace. Could you edit your question to include the whole of it?

Comment: I have just added it. thanks.

Comment: That looks to be a problem with EclipseLink for which Spring Boot does not have any auto-configuration. The message suggests you're missing a method on your `RequestArray` class: "NoSuchMethodException: com.mycell.comet.router.model.RequestArray.setRequests([Ljava.sql.SQLData;)"

Comment: Actually I dont use EclipseLink, and I think some configuration is activating it. I tried to exclude JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class but they did not worked.

Comment: You shouldn't need to exclude any auto configuration. You are deploying to web logic, a server which also ships with a plethora on features and jars. The default is to use the plethora on features and jars from the server instead of what is packaged inside your application. So remove the excludes and include a weblogic specific deployment descriptor telling the server you want to prefer application classes over server classes.

Comment: I already excluded the followings and it did not worked either. do you know which packages to be exluced. 

    `<wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.eclipse.persistence</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>`

Comment: No as that depends on your application. Weblogic also ships with its own Spring version you might want to add that as well. Isn't there a quick switch to toggle class loading in web logic?